AWS Patch Policy Failing To Attach
I am currently getting the below error, but the one server I am testing with has an IAM policy that has ""s3:GetObject" and the arn listed below is in the resource.  Every time I try and attach the policy it fails.
Invoke-PatchBaselineOperation : User: arn:aws:sts::813335082128:assumed-role/iam_roletest/i-07aa8f3aa72467b39 is
not authorized to perform: s3:GetObject on resource:
"arn:aws:s3:::aws-quicksetup-patchpolicy-813335082128-55555/baseline_overrides.json"
